# tabularray and babel french

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray, babel-french

I need to use `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` but it causes an error in the folowing example.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{circuitikz} %to draw an electrical circuit
%\usetikzlibrary{babel} %I need this library because I use french babel and circuitikz
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},vlines,hlines}
        $y=2x$
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \begin{axis}[
                xlabel = {$x$},
                ylabel = {$y$},
                ]
                \addplot[domain=0:10]{2*x};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please copypaste the error you get when compiling? Might get more eyeballs, or even give more expert users an immediate hunch of the root of the problem :)

Comment: Put `\shorthandoff{;}` before the `\begin{tblr}`

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I thought the `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` command took care of the semicolon.

Comment: ...yes, it takes care of the semicolon *in tikz pictures*... ;-) (anyway, with Unicode input, `shorthands=off` in babel is normally safer....

Comment: BTW, this is not really related to `circuitikz`...

Comment: The problem is probably the inclusion of `tikzpicture` in `tblr`. `tblr` reads its argument completely, and then it fixes the catcode of `;` and then it is too late for `tikz` to change that.

Comment: Active characters are painful but necessary in French *with older engines* like pdftex.  `babel-french` no longer uses active characters neither with luatex nor with xetex.  Having to write in French is one more reason to switch  to these modern engines ;-)

Comment: @DanielFlipo I use pdftex instead of luatex because of lower compile time. But luatex indeed solves my problems.